# Batch scripts to read a list then delete from a directory

Tags: batch

I need to have a batch script that reads a file, and from a list in that file deletes items from a directory.

Comment: You might be having troubles getting an answer if you aren't able to show what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will delete all the files in the directories listed, but not the directory itself.

```
FOR %%A IN (list.txt) DO DEL %%A\*
```

If you want to just delete the whole folder, try this

```
FOR %%A IN (list.txt) DO RMDIR /S /Q %%A
```